# horizontal shoot & score

Tags: javascript, function, browser, phaser-framework

I'm doing a idle game project, where the player(fox) shots a projectile to destroy the trashbags and cans and through that, they gain coins. However, I wanted to do it with custom classes but couldn't do it.

[image: the game screen]

I have all the visual part alling (the sprites and animations) and for the script, the fox should shoot by clicking in the fox sprite using the pointer function (the function is ok by the way). So, I wanted to know what alternatives I have to make my game functional.

Oh, and for more info, I found this video about it, but it didn't resolve it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qs5xmT6Upsc&list=PLDyH9Tk5ZdFzEu_izyqgPFtHJJXkc79no&index=9

I've used the same code as him but replace the name of the variables for my game, but it didn't work either.

Comment: What excatly does _"didn't work"_ ? Are error created,.in the browser console? how does *your* code look like? because in phaser, you can build you game functional or with "custom" classes, it is more or less the same.

Comment: P.s.: Checkout this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to improve your chances of getting _(good)_ answers here on stackoverflow.

Comment: First of all, sorry if the question was badly drafted, I made it on rush 'cause it's quite urgent. The problem is the projectiles doesn't appear when the function is called by clicking on the fox. I'll provide my github link if you want to check the code, it's to big to just upload some lines here (and don't mind the portuguese comments). https://github.com/RickPedroza/LittleFox

Comment: you don't have to be sorry, I just wanted you help you get a answer faster, and that your question doesn't get closed before, you get an answer. posting the link to your github helps, but doesn't make it easy to help. [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be the key, as mentioned in the article above.

Comment: glad it worked, could you accept my answer if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems, that I can identify on the first glance *(btw. I usually don't debug code on SO, but I had a good day)*:

1. You are not passing the scene as context to the `on` function in line 227 of the file Scene2.js ([checkout documentation for details](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#on__anchor))
   **Solution:** pass the *"context"* to the function call.

   ```
   fox.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
       ...
   }, this); // <- "this" has to be added
   ```
2. After fixing this the program continues, but runs into the next issue, line 4 of slash.js.
   **Solution:** add this line `this.fox = fox;` before the ende of the `create` function in the Scene2.js file.

> **Tipps:**
>
> 1. When working with javascript in a browser, check the browser console for errors the will help solve the problems / errors. This was the initial error:
>    [image: initial error]
> 2. Checkout the official example for working [code examples](https://phaser.io/examples)
> 3. Checkout the previously mention [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), if you need/want fast help on Stackoverflow.